# Disable panning/dragging on leaflet map for div within map

Tags: leaflet

Does anyone know how to suppress panning when you click and drag over top of a div box embedded within the map itself?

For example [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html), when you click and drag over top of the legend, the map drags with you. I want to suppress that function.
I am aware if this technique, but i want to know if this is the only way:

```
map.dragging.disable();
```

Comment: I have implemented similar functionaility using a jQuery .hover listener (using handlerIn and handlerOut to disable and enable dragging).  Not sure if that is an option for you:  http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using [the example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html) from the Leaflet website, note where the `L.Control` object is instantiated as `info`; this is the `<div>` box in the upper-right associated with the map's hover interaction. Here is where it is defined in `index.html` from the Leaflet example:

```
    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(map);
```

**To disable the dragging when a user's cursor is inside this `<div>` box**, add an event listener to the `HTMLElement` (a `<div>` element) that contains the `L.Control` object:

```
    // Disable dragging when user's cursor enters the element
    info.getContainer().addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        map.dragging.disable();
    });

    // Re-enable dragging when user's cursor leaves the element
    info.getContainer().addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        map.dragging.enable();
    });
```

Recall that `map` was defined as the `L.Map` instance earlier.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur, i am familiar with this approach. I was hoping someone might offer a solution using css as in pointer-events:auto or pointer-events:none or somthing like those, which do not quite work for me. If no one else posts a better solution, I will give you the check, as it will mean that that is the best solution.

Comment: I should like to see that as well. It would be nice if CSS could solve this problem, but which element should have its pointer events managed? The `leaflet-control` element is contained by the `leaflet-container` element and the latter is receiving the pointer events that trigger zoom and panning.

Comment: I have been trying to put it on the div of interest to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, and that makes sense: the `<div>` of interest is a child of `leaflet-control` which itself is inside of `leaflet-container`. The events are received by the parent (`leaflet-container`) before the child (`leaflet-control`).

Answer (score 20):

An alternative solution to that is to stop event propagation with JavaScript (like it's done for Leaflet controls, e.g. zoom buttons):

```
var div = L.DomUtil.get('div_id');
if (!L.Browser.touch) {
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
    L.DomEvent.on(div, 'mousewheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
} else {
    L.DomEvent.on(div, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the easy way is,

```js
$('div').on("mousedown", L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
```

It will stop the dragging of the map inside the div element.

Comment: This is a very simple and elegant solution. If you don't use jQuery, this is roughly the same in pure JavaScript: `document.getElementById("mydiv").onmousedown = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;`.

Answer (score 4):

A small optimization for the solution from [@Arthur](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104609/164493).
Use `mousedown` and `mouseup`. So it didn't trigger when you just drag over your div. Only when you start dragging inside your div.

**Attention** use mouseup for the whole html

```
$('.yourDiv').mousedown( function() {
    map.dragging.disable();
});

$('html').mouseup( function() {
    map.dragging.enable();
});
```